# How to ignore repated realtime data and accept only unique data in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, unique

Hello friends I m developing an app that can write address accordind to lat lng. but most of time its repeting same address couple of time. I want to do it nothing if the last address is same and write only if previous address is different. 
for example.
 my output is somthing like this 
add1, add1, add1, add2, add2, add3, add4...
i need 
add1,add2,add3,add4,add5,
or 
add1,add2,add1,add2,add3,... also acceptable but not countinous add couple of time.

Comment: http://jszen.com/best-way-to-get-unique-values-of-an-array-in-javascript.7.html  . did you get a chance to google?

Answer (score 0):

```
function pushAddress(addresses, newAddress)
{
    if(newAddress == addresses[addresses.length-1]) //check most recent address
    {
        //Potential address equals the most recent one
        //Handle appropriately
    } else {
        adresses.push(newAddress);
    }
}

addrss = ["A1", "A2", "A3"];

pushAddress(addrss, "A3");
//addrss = ["A1", "A2", "A3"]

pushAddress(addrss, "A4");
//addrss = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]
```

The top function should do it.